# Direct fetches via browser are ~2x faster than cURL

Tags: php, curl

I have a webcam that I'm trying to set up to be public.  The webcam is publically available, but every time the number of viewers doubles, so does the refresh latency.  Therefore, I'm just going to set up a simple rebroadcasting website that doesn't sacrifice quality or need paid 3rd party support to handle things.

Currently, the latency fetching an image while directly connecting to the camera is 700ms.  This is verified via chrome debugger.  If I script a cURL download request, the latency according to curl_getinfo averages 1.4 seconds.  Using file_put_contents() instead has the same duration.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://path.to/image.jpg');
$fp = fopen('./localImage.jpg', 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
$ci = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($ci);
fclose($fp);
```

Any idea why this is happening?

```
array(22) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(33) "http://path.to/image.jpg"
  ["content_type"]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(124)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(64)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(1.40834)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(4.7E-5)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.082317)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.083356)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(60331)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(42838)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(60331)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.318247)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: There's no way that you're making the request twice somehow, is there?  I know that's kind of a silly question, but when something like this takes almost exactly twice as long as some other method, that usually seems to be the culprit.

Comment: Good idea, and there is a loop, but the code posted above is exactly what's being executed, so there's no double request going on...

Comment: I think I had a problem like this before where it is actually called twice because of some settings (but my memory is real blurry), take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158985/php-curl-script-run-twice-when-printing-return-string (I know the guy says it doesn't seem to work but just a suggestion)