# PHP cURL Double Submission When Fields Array Printed

Tags: php, arrays, forms, curl, form-submit

I'm using cURL to submit a form on another webpage and have ran into a weird phenomenon:

When I use `print_r($fields)` to print out the post fields BEFORE I pass the array to cURL request and submit it, the form is submitted twice. When I remove that line from the script, the double submission disappears.

Why is printing the array causing a double submission?

```
//set POST variables
$fields = array();
$fields['input-name'] = 'input-value';

print_r($fields); //causes double submission

//open connection
$url = 'http://blah.com/blah/blah';
$request = curl_init($url);

//send post data
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

// output the response
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($request);
```

Comment: Quick question, how did you tell that it was submitting twice?

Comment: @Ibu I have access to the database that the other form puts submission data into.

Comment: I wonder why did you set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to _TRUE_, only to echo the return yourself?  I searched your problem, and changing this helped in some ocasions. (no explanation to the double submital) [php curl script run twice when printing return string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158985/php-curl-script-run-twice-when-printing-return-string)

Comment: `print_r` doesn't affect your form submission for short.

Comment: @OctavioGalindo PHP's official documentation states that `curl_exec` "Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure. " So an echo still seems necessary, and it's not printing my results twice. Thanks for looking that up! However, I already ran across that one. The only thing that has fixed my double submission issue is removing `print_r($fields);`.

Comment: @JaredChu ...except when it does. And I have ran into one of those rare cases. The question is why.

Comment: Try to see if you have an output buffer problem. The behavior is very unusual.

Comment: @Ibu How would you suggest doing that?

Comment: @HunterS I did test on my localhost and it didn't happen.